# How can I add a line to file using bitbucket pipeline build

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting, terminal

I have made a bitbucket pipeline, but I want to make changes to configuration file each time during after its build

I want to add "Staging" each time after the build of the project to a specific file...

Ok redting step by step-:

Step 1 -:
[image]

I want this method to be done in my pipeline , I want to use staging.pubxml (for now its using local by default)

Step 2-:

[image]

After that I want publish method to be File System and want to specify target loacation for it!

Step 3-:

[image]

Step 3 just skip cause I know by just adding -c release its done ,I added it cause when after configuring we click on save the next step can be understood

Step 4-:

[image]

After clicking on save you will see that staging profile gets tick marked meaning its changed so , inside data also changes and I need to add this
Staging

I have the code ready just that through pipeline I can't get staging profile. This is my pipeline

```
          name: Build 
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
          script:
          - cd AdminPortal_WebAPI
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils
          - apt-get install sed
          - dotnet publish AdminPortal_WebAPI.csproj -c Release -o pipelineoutput/
          - sed -i '11 a <EnvironmentName>Staging</EnvironmentName>' Properties/PublishProfiles/staging.pubxml
          - sed -i -e '6 s/rm-gs5u21x7xlbcs399n.mysql.singapore.rds.aliyuncs.com/127.0.0.1/g' -e '6 s/\(cardbuzz\)/root/2' -e '6 s/456RTYfgh\$\$/7889/g' appsettings.Staging.json
          - dotnet build --configuration Release -o pipelineoutput/
          - cd pipelineoutput
          - cp -r ./ ../../build/admin_webapi
```

Problem is its not choosing staging.pubxml and thus cannot be updated.

Error-:
`/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.426/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(171,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "%ProgramW6432%/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" is invalid. [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/AdminPortal_WebAPI/AdminPortal_WebAPI.csproj]`

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! I am afraid this isn't enough detail for us to be able to help you. What _exactly_ do you want to add, and to what file? Where in the file? What operating system are you using? Please [edit] your question and add some detail. Show us your input and then also show us the output you want to get from that input.

Comment: @terdon done please check now